# Is there any way to specify a CSS selector for a lonely child?

Tags: css, css-selectors

I want to have a different style for a list item when the list only has one element, is there any way to do that with just CSS?

Comment: Depends on where that <li> element is. I would say if its in the middle of a string of <li> elements, then you would need to use nth-child selector

Comment: @Keith: "when the list only has one element" then there cannot be a whole string of <li> elements.

Answer (score 13):

The selector you want is `:only-child`

So you can use in css: `li:only-child { }` or `p:only-child {}` Apply-it on your element

Comment: Awesome, I was totally unaware of it xD Give me 12 minutes to accept because I cannot right now :p

Comment: As a bonus, "only" rhymes with "lonely".